# Changing privilege rights on Arch Linux for a particular program

Tags: arch-linux, privileges, chown

I am quite new to linux and have had issues surrounding every program that I install. Basically, anything that is placed outside of my home directory requires a `sudo` call prior to opening/executing. I cannot write to files, open usb devices, or run programs that exist outside of this directory (specifically, above this directory).

I know this is a privilege problem, but I come here to ask how this can be permanently stopped. How can I configure things such that when programs are installed I do not have to manually find the executable and change its privilege requirements?

Comment: You shouldn't do that, things are setup this way for your own safety and security

Comment: Most of the programs are installed in `/usr/bin` where you have the rights to read and execute files. So what is really your need ?